# Data Blending Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am creating a data blend and combining 2 excel files. I have volume
data dummy as primary data source & lifecycle dummy as secondary.
The common key is Ticket Id. Have created a calculated field to find the ticket
time which is Ticket Time =

```
DATEDIFF('day',ATTR([LifeCycle Dummy].[Assigned]),ATTR([LifeCycle Dummy].[Closed]))
```

Now i am not able to figure out how to show average ticket time per month or
at various other dimensions available such as priority, status etc. If i
remove the ticket id and only keep ticket time then the blend does not work. Do
advice if this can be achieved. Attached picture for reference.
 [image: tableau]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show average ticket time per month, or any data based calculation, you'll need to join the data sources on Date also - looking at your screenshot they don;t appear to be linked yet. To enable them to be linked both fields must have exactly the same name, then you can click the paperclip icon next to the field to link it.

Comment: Sure Ben will add, in case i do not have the date column is there an alternate. Because i have 6-7 different column that are same in both the tables. Does it make sense

Comment: Ah I see - have you created a join on any of the fields, for example Ticket Id?

Comment: Yes on data blend i have ticket id as primary key. apart from this there are couple more which are common in both the tables. Unfortunately i cannot share the tableau file on the forum or else i could have shared and would have been even clearer.

Comment: It's obviously hard to tell without seeing your workbook, but there are data blends made at the data import stage, then linked fields, which behave differently. If your issue is that you're not able to make the calculations you want on the blended data, because its blended, I would suggest adding the second data source that you added to your blend as a new data source, then you will be also to make calculations across the data sources without the blends transforming any data.